# $Avg aggregation in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to calculate the average of field using $avg in mongodb.
code:-

```
DoctorsReview.aggregate([
        { 
            $match: { 
                doctor: doctorsId
            }
        },
        { 
            $group: {
            _id: null, 
            averageRating: { $avg: "$rating" },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
            } 
        }],function(error, result){
             if(error)
                   console.log(error);
             console.log(result);
});
```

The issues is when i hit the query for first time,its returning an empty array, but when i hit it again,its returning me the result expected in previous hit.

FYI I am trying to calculate the average of rating corresponding to doctorsId in DoctorsReview model.

Please help.

DoctorsReview sample :-

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56b473b0b9d8b5b01c6d1529"), 
"rating" : NumberInt(4), 
"review" : "Poor", 
"user" : ObjectId("5673a0e86a8141c00c85a743"), 
"doctor" : ObjectId("56b1cbb4e8e806f8229c1afa"), 
"date" : ISODate("2010-12-12T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
"time" : NumberInt(19), 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

expected response:-

```
[{ _id: null, averageRating: 4, count: 1}];
```

so when i hit for the first time, i get empty array as a response, but when the server is hit again, i get the expected response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below, I didn`t try it.

```
{ 
        $match: { 
            doctor: doctorsId
        }
    },
    { 
        $group: {
        _id: null, 
        averageRating: { $avg: "$rating" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
        } 
    },{$project:{_id:0, rating:"$averageRating", __v:"$count"}}
```